# Android app Faking a Shutdown, tapping all inputs

Tags: android, powermanager

I need to create an application wherein, while the application is running, it must fake a shutdown, the Phone must look like its not running(or its switched off), however the application must be running in the background.

The Application must be able to trap all the inputs, and on a particular key combination the application must show its Settings Menu.

I am not sure if this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your user scenario?  What is the purpose of the app?

Comment: Fortunately, it's not possible for an app to do this.  Please don't harass or play tricks on users.

Comment: For security reasons a basic app cannot intercept the Home or power buttons...

Comment: @Simon Thanks for replying. Sorry i cannot describe the entire purpose, thats a bussiness idea that someone else owns :-)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Our Bussiness Objective won't do anything like that :-)

Comment: But it could be abused if you implement it. Good intentions isn't everything.

Comment: Fortunately they can't implement it.

Comment: @Keyser No It cannot be .. The application won't even be available on Market, and won't be distributed at all.

Comment: I would be happy if someone can give me some pointers on this. And what best can i achieve.

Comment: It could also be abused simply if it was possible. That's kind of what the others were trying to say (I guess it's still possible, but Android won't make it easy for you :p)

Comment: @Keyser Any Pointers on "I guess its still possible" :P ?

Comment: Well, I don't have any experience with it but the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) might be worth looking into (though I think it's mainly to control memory and such, the usual benefits with C)

Comment: "The application won't even be available on Market, and won't be distributed at all." Sounds like you're trying to play a trick on/harass someone you know personally.

Answer (score 2):

You are welcome to download the Android source code, modify it to contain this sort of malware, compile that into your own ROM mod, and install that ROM mod on whatever devices you are able to.